# How to remove ListBoxitem selection border or defautl margin in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'd like to hide/remove the border of ListBox and listboxitem , and also selected listboxitems border.

And also one thing how to remove click feel from ListView.

Please check it attached screen [image]

I Just want remove the margin between listbox item and border around selected listboxitem.

How do I do this?

```
                Background="#0C2C40"
                BorderThickness="0"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"                    
                Margin="0,0,0,0"                            
                ItemsSource="{Binding ListBrand}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Width="400" Height="60" Background="#113F5B"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,1" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BrandsTextblock}" Text="{Binding Rank}"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BrandsTextblock}" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="#FDBE0F" Style="{StaticResource BrandsTextblock}" Text="{Binding Insertion}"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>

                                </Grid>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Comment: can you show me your XAML code?

Comment: Show XAML code related to Listbox and to remove the click feel you need to edit the template or add style to that particular ListView.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,

Comment: Hi Janak/ Nathiel, I have added my xaml code, please check it and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want to show the user the selection border and you don't want the margin then why not use ListView. And the changes that you are trying to achieve can be easily be done in ListView. Like you can set IsItemClickEnabled to true or false or SelectionMode property to none. Also by setting the itemcontainer style you can get rid of the margin.

```
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.   Before this I have used ListView and I did same changes as you said  IsItemClickEnabled to true or false or SelectionMode property to none, after this changes listview items are behaving like button feel, if we click on any record its seem click feel. what should I do if I dont want click feel in listview item.

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030182/disabling-tap-animation-in-listview-in-wp-8-1